# Adding a date picker using fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker

I have a question about setting up a fragmentManager.  I am working on an application that has a setup page and within it has a button for selecting the date.
I have a fragment for a date picker and a layout for the datepicker.

I was trying to setup the fragmentManager in my actviity as so:

```
     //Setup fragment manager
    android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    //fragment transaction
    android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    //add fragments
    ft.add(R.id.dialog_date);
    ft.commit();
```

I am having issues with the ft.add part, I am trying to add the fragment layout for my date picker.  I am not clear if this is the correct way.  Along with the date picker I am adding a time picker as well.  Do I add it the same way?

```
    ft.add(R.id.timepicker)
```

I have setup my button click using an intent to get the date picker.  I don't think this is the correct way to call up the date picker.

```
    //button click for date. user clicks button and a date picker fragment is enabled.
    mDateButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.eventDateButton);

    mDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(NewEventSetupActivity.this, DatePickerFragment.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

Am I on the right track the way I have this setup?  or is there an easier way to this?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use an intent when launching a new fragment. You simply use the fragment manager, this is pretty simple to do if you use a dialog fragment for the date picker.

With a dialog fragment your onClick can be something as simple as this:

```
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
  DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
  newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

Check this out, its a great tutorial to show a good looking date picker as a dialog: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#DatePicker

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help I will go through the tutorial and post back in a bit if I have more issues.  Thanks agaain.

Comment: @DejanRistic--thanks for the tutorial and your help I was able to get the time and date pickers set up.  The only issue I have which I think stems from not using the fragmentManager correctly is how do I set up my activity.  Thanks again.